# main module not found in react native

Tags: react-native

hello can anyone help me resolve this problem?

error: Error: While trying to resolve module `child_process` from file `C:\Users\NP\Desktop\project\SamTask\node_modules\@jest\core\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js`, the package `C:\Users\NP\Desktop\project\SamTask\node_modules\child_process\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\NP\Desktop\project\SamTask\node_modules\child_process\index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- C:\Users\NP\Desktop\project\SamTask\node_modules\child_process\index.js(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
- C:\Users\NP\Desktop\project\SamTask\node_modules\child_process\index.js\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\NP\Desktop\project\SamTask\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:65:15)
  at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\NP\Desktop\project\SamTask\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
  at Object.resolve (C:\Users\NP\Desktop\project\SamTask\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
  at C:\Users\NP\Desktop\project\SamTask\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:434:31
  at Array.map ()
  at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\NP\Desktop\project\SamTask\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:431:18)
  at C:\Users\NP\Desktop\project\SamTask\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
  at Generator.next ()
  at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\NP\Desktop\project\SamTask\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
  at _next (C:\Users\NP\Desktop\project\SamTask\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:107:9)

Comment: It is simple. I guess you installed a node module named `child_process` and its main path method is wrong. Is it your library?